# knockout.js best way to bind html string in textarea with line breaks

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, escaping, textarea

I've got the html string that I'd like bind with knockout.js and display it in textarea, and of course allow submitting it after some editing. What is the proper way to achieve that?

When I use HTML binding, I can bind `one <br/> two` string and it displays the same in textarea, but after submitting, I get the encoded string `one&lt;br/&gt;two`, which isn't too bad as I can handle it later, but there's still the line breaks issue.

Basically I'd like to preserve:

- original line breaks
- original html text

Now, when I pass:

```
<html>
<body>
```

using both `value` and `html` binding, in knockout I get script exception, as new lines are not handled. Special characters are encoded as well:

```
Content: ko.observable("&lt;html&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show what you've attempted so far.

Comment: As I said I tried html binding and value binding of course. I think there's no need to paste the code since it's nothing unusual. Moreover I feel like the solution isn't only about binding method.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `btoa` to encode the actual value so that no munging goes on in submission. Then you would use `atob` to decode on the server. Here's a little demo that lets you see how various treatments of html come out.

```js
ko.applyBindings({stuff: ko.observable('<h1>Foo</h1>hi\nthere')});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<textarea data-bind="value:stuff"></textarea>
<pre data-bind="text:stuff"></pre>
<hr />
<pre data-bind="html:stuff"></pre>
<hr />
<pre data-bind="text: btoa(stuff())"></pre>
```